# Is there a result in finite dimension as : a normed vector space is isomorphic or embedded in the dual space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ a normed vector space. I know that if $E$ has finite dimension then $E$ and $E'$ (the topological dual space) are isomorphic. In case where $E$ has infinite dimension, do we have such a result ?

- I know that if $E$ is reflexive, then $E$ and $E''$ (the topological bidual) are isomorphic. So maybe, if $E$ is reflexive $E\cong E'\cong E''$ ?
- If $E$ is a Hilbert space, does $E\cong E'$ always ?

Comment: One obvious counterexample is when  $E$ is not complete. Since dual spaces are complete an incomplete space can never be isomorphic to its dual.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: And if $E$ is complete ?

Comment: A Hilbert space is always isomorphic to its topological dual. The isomorphism is given by $v \mapsto \langle v, \cdot \rangle$ (or $\langle \cdot , v \rangle$ depending on your convention of scalar product)

Answer (score 1):

No!  Even in finite-dimensional case, $E$ and $E'$ are not isomorphic normed spaces (i.e., isometrically isomorphic because the norm is, strictly speaking, part of the structure here), only isomorphic as topological vector spaces.  In infinite dimension the situation is worse, you don't necessarily get a TVS-isomorphism between $E$ and $E'$ even if $E$ is reflexive (in particular, $E$ is complete).

An example is $E=\ell^p$, $p\in(1,\infty)$, then $E'=\ell^{p/(p-1)}$ and we know every continuous map $\ell^p\to\ell^q$ is compact if $q<p$ (Pitt's compactness theorem), so one of $E\to E'$, $E'\to E''\cong E$ is not an isomorphism if $p\neq 2$.

Of course, by Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces, $H'\cong H$ for any Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: I agree that in finite dimension, $E$ and $E'$ are not isometric, but the should be isomorphic as normed space, no ?

Comment: Isomorphic as normed spaces is stronger than isometric.

Comment: The first part of the answer is wrong and even misleading. If $E$ is finite dimensional then  certainly it is isomorphic to its dual. OP did not talk about isometric isomorphisms.

Comment: That depends on the category you are working in.  I'm saying is that, *strictly speaking*, two equivalent but not identical norms gives different normed spaces so "isomorphism" should reflect that.  For most analysis purpose, being Lipshitz equivalent is enough, hence the sloppy use of the term isomorphic, but that means we are working in the quotient category.

Comment: I don't get why if $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic as normed space, then they are isometric. For example, let $f:U\to V$ such an isomorphism. Why $\|f(x)\|_V=\|x\|_U$ ? I guess $f$ has to be an homeomorphism, thus $$\|x\|_u=\|f^{-1}(f(x))\|_U\leq C\|f(x)\|_V\leq D\|x\|_U.$$ But why $D=1$ ?